# Can parse cache replace core data

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm building a simple contact directory with CRUD functions, and I want to have editing functionality offline. My database for the contacts will be stored on a Parse.com backend. Would this be possible using the Parse cache functionality, or would it be better for me to resort to using Core Data?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it can't. Parse simply caches the results of your queries. This is extremely limiting and not the same as caching all of your PFObjects. For example, say you ran a query for all of your "contacts" PFObjects. The only thing you would be able to do with the cache is run the exact same query again later (and get the exact same result). You couldn't even query for a subset of that cached data.

Another issue is the cached objects will not be updated with any changes your user is making to your PFObjects. For example, say a user is editing contacts offline and your code is calling `saveEventually` to save those changes to Parse when possible. When you get a cached query result the user's changes will not be reflected in your PFObjects. The same goes for deleted and added PFObjects I believe. This would make offline use terrible. Here is a thread from the Parse forum that touches on this subject:

https://www.parse.com/questions/does-saving-an-object-supposed-to-update-the-local-cache-of-a-query-on-these-objects

I have seen Parse developers mention improved caching of Parse objects coming at some point in the future. However, this feature does not exist yet and there is no knowing when it will come. In the mean time, if you want to support offline use you have to use Core Data or some other local store. FTASync (which I have never used) is designed to sync Parse objects with Core Data:

https://github.com/itsniper/FTASync

You could also write your own code to sync the two sets of data.

Comment: Quite a lot of work involved there, isn't it!
If the Parse cache allowed for much finer grain control, then I think it could potentially replace the need for Core Data for lots of apps.

Comment: Are there any more up to date libraries than FTASync? This hasn't been updated for some time now. Good answer, by the way.

Comment: @doctorBroctor Thanks! I don't know of any alternatives to FTASync. I have gone the route of writing my own code to handle this and haven't investigate other options in quite a while.

Answer (score 6):

The Parse iOS/OSX SDK provides a local datastore which can be used to store and retrieve PFObjects, even when the network is unavailable. To enable this functionality, add libsqlite3.dylib and call [Parse enableLocalDatastore] before your call to setApplicationId:clientKey:.

As stated in [the Parse documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS):

> You can store a PFObject in the local datastore by pinning it. Pinning
>   a PFObject is recursive, just like saving, so any objects that are
>   pointed to by the one you are pinning will also be pinned. When an
>   object is pinned, every time you update it by fetching or saving new
>   data, the copy in the local datastore will be updated automatically.
>   You don't need to worry about it at all.
>
> ```
> PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
> gameScore[@"score"] = 1337;
> gameScore[@"playerName"] = @"Sean Plott";
> gameScore[@"cheatMode"] = @NO;
> [gameScore pinInBackground];
> ```
>
> If you have multiple objects, you can pin them all at once with the
>   pinAllInBackground convenience method.
>
> ```
> [PFObject pinAllInBackground:listOfObjects];
> ```
>
> Retrieving an object from the local datastore works just like
>   retrieving one over the network. The only difference is calling the
>   fromLocalDatastore method to tell the PFQuery where to look for its
>   results.
>
> ```
> PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
> [query fromLocalDatastore];
> [[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"xWMyZ4YE"] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
>   if (task.error) {
>     // Something went wrong.
>     return task;
>   }
>
>   // task.result will be your game score
>   return task;
> }];
> ```
>
> Any PFQuery can be used with the local datastore just as with the
>   network. The results will include any object you have pinned that
>   matches the query. Any unsaved changes you have made to the object
>   will be considered when evaluating the query. So you can find a local
>   object that matches, even if it was never returned from the server for
>   this particular query.
>
> ```
> PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
> [query fromLocalDatastore];
> [query whereKey:@"playerName" equalTo:@"Joe Bob"];
> [[query findObjectsInBackground] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
>   if (task.error) {
>     NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
>     return task;
>   }
>
>   NSLog(@"Retrieved %d", task.result.count);
>   return task;
> }];
> ```
>
> When you are done with an object and no longer need it to be in the
>   local datastore, you can simply unpin it.
>
> ```
> [gameScore unpinInBackground];
> ```
>
> There's also a method to unpin several objects at once.
>
> ```
> [PFObject unpinAllInBackground:listOfObjects];
> ```

For more information on using Parse's local datastore check the Local Datastore documentation provided for iOS/OSX on parse's website.

Comment: But the question remains, does this REPLACE core data, or work side by side with it? I'm guessing it replaces, but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: it replaces core data.

Comment: This works but not always as expected. Especially when trying to delete objects once they have been pinned via saveEventually... not enough documentation for such a big feature.

Comment: Be aware that Local Datastore is deprecated; I discovered this after finding serious performance issues using it: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-dotNET/issues/237

Answer (score 1):

No it can not. It's no where near the same, I suggest https://github.com/itsniper/FTASync